# Quarkus - logging in JSON with custom fields

Tags: json, logging, log4j2, quarkus, x-correlation-id

I would like to add into JSON format log correlationId field as a part of MDC, i.e.: %X{correlationId}. I have tried various syntax with additional-field directive, but I'm not able to do it. Is there any way how to define my own JSON log message format?

Comment: If you can add additional extensions, take a look at https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-logging-json.

Comment: I did it, but I have not found anything useful. JSON format in quarkus seems very rigid without chance to change it. I was able to ad via additional-field extra field, but only with string constant, not with replacing value like %X{correlationId}. Also I noticed, that MDC context is not persist by default.

Comment: With the referenced quarkiverse library, you should be able to modify the JSON in a custom way. I'll maybe try to get you an example if I find the time. Regarding MDC, what do you mean it's not persistent?